# JPA when to use Path of entity type instead of Join?

Tags: jpa, join

An example in JPA spec:

```
CriteriaQuery<Customer> q = cb.createQuery(Customer.class);
Root<Customer> customer = q.from(Customer.class);
Join<Customer, Order> order = customer.join(Customer_.orders);
q.where(cb.equal(cb.treat(order.get(Order_.product), Book.class)
.get(Book_.name),
"Iliad"));
q.select(customer);
```

order.product is a path in the where clause. If it is not join, how to access
the name attribute of the product(Book)? Is it actually a table join when translated to SQL?  If this is the case, what is the difference between path
and join in this example?

```
    Order        Product
----------      -------------
    productId    id     name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it actually a table join when translated to SQL?

Yes, it is.

> what is the difference between path and join in this example?

Let me explain using JPQL, it will be clearer. Your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c
JOIN c.orders o
WHERE o.product.name = 'Illiad'
```

Single-valued associations can be queried both by implicit joins (using path navigation) and explicit joins (using `JOIN`). It is important to remember that implicit joins are inner joins by default. The above query is therefore equivalent to:

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c
JOIN c.orders o
JOIN o.product p
WHERE p.name = 'Illiad'
```

This syntax is more verbose, but allows you to specify the join type, if need be.

Multi-valued associations behave a little differently. The following query:

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c
JOIN c.orders.product.name = 'Illiad'
```

will not compile. The shorthand syntax cannot be used here, as `c.orders` represents the collection as a whole and not its individual elements. To refer to individual elements, we need to *dereference* the collection, which makes the `JOIN c.orders o` syntax mandatory (the alias `o` now refers to individual elements inside `c.orders`)

On the other hand, no explicit joins are required when refering to the multi-valued association as a whole, e.g.:

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c
WHERE SIZE(c.orders) > 5

SELECT c.orders FROM Customer c
```